# Google maps api: Customising the MapTypeControl for separate map overlays

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have lots of slices of (non-geographical) data that I'm trying to
view via google maps. It basically breaks down into N 'maps', each
containing M 'layers'.

This sample shows basically what I want to do:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple.html

I can get it to switch between two different maps by providing two
custom MapTypes (much like the Map/Sattelite toggle in the sample),
but I can't figure out how to make it so I can toggle on and off an
additional overlay layer (like the 'terrain' checkbox).

The official docs vaguely mention this (
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#MapTypeInterface
) but unfortunately the bit I'm after ('See Adding MapType Controls
below') is a dead link, and I can't find this bit of the
documentation.

Does anyone know where the documentation on how to control the drop-
down toggle boxes exists?

Thanks

Comment: Could it be that the 'sub-layers' (Hybrid, Terrain) are a special case of MapType, because they are added to the mapTypeControl as any other MapType, but appear as a child of a certain layer?

Comment: Have you solved your issue? I have the same problem, but not successfult to find the solution yet. Looks like I will have to implement my own map type control, consuming my custom maps (with overlays) and also standard google maps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have a particular overlay appear or disappear based on a checkbox, you can check out http://geojason.info/2010/overlay-map-management-with-google-maps-api-v3/.

However, that involves checkboxes that are not actually on the map.  They need to go in a sidebar or above the map or whatever.  If you are hoping to be able to add things to the control where the "terrain" and the "layer" checkbox appear, I don't think there's any hooks in Google Maps API v3 to do that.  I'd be happy to be wrong, but I don't think it's simple and I would expect any solution that managed to accomplish it would be brittle.

Comment: Yes, I found that earlier but it's not really what I want to do - I'd like to add drop-down menus like the 'terrain' option in the sample map. While I could add my own checkboxes it won't be as compact and I'll have to recreate google's style or it'll look horribly out of place.