# Custom overlay map types and mapTypeControl

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've successfully added OSM as a new base map type to my Google Maps API aplication.

Next I've added a new overlay map type, which adds hill shading to the map.
The documentation on overlay map types on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=en#OverlayMapTypes says:

*"[...]you can add the map type to an existing MapType[...]"*

*"Overlay map types will display on top of any base map they are attached to."*

And *"The following example is identical to the previous one except that we've created a tile overlay MapType on top of the ROADMAP map type:"*

But in the code example the overlay map type is always shown on either map type you chose.

1. How can I make my hillshading overlay map type to be only shown on map type "roadmap" and my custom "OSM" map type? **EDIT:** To be more precise: Actually I want to know, if there is a way to do this automatically like the docs above suggest. I know, how to do this manually by listening to the maptypeid_changed event.
2. Is there a way to add my overlay map type to the mapTypeControl as a checkbox like it's done with "Labels" on the default satellite map type or "terrain" on the roadmap map type?
   **EDIT:** Until some days ago the official docs above suggested a way to do this, but did not describe it exactly and the linked example was broken (404-link). Thy user here found the same issue: [Google maps api: Customising the MapTypeControl for separate map overlays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169555/google-maps-api-customising-the-maptypecontrol-for-separate-map-overlays)

**EDIT:**
I've posted the jsFiddl of my current solution below.

Comment: I ran into this same problem, but instead of going the _supported_ route of adding my own control, I implemented an incredibly hackish solution that relies on the current DOM structure of the existing controls.  I posted my solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099655/custom-map-tile-overlay-issues/28376677#28376677) in case anyone is interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, looks like there is no native way, to bind an overlay map type to a base map type or to use Googles map type control for overlay map type.

**So here is what I have finally done, to work around this issue:** http://jsfiddle.net/lejared/720L7wu0/3/

```
var ReliefCtrl = {/* see fiddle */};
```

I've build a custom control (with the look an feel of the native Google maps controls). This Control toggles my overlay map type (Hillshading). You can define a array of base map types suitable for this overlay map type. The control will than show/hide itself automatically if a suitable base map type is selected.

*2017-02-01: Updates fiddle to match new native look of googles map controls.*

Comment: Complex code needed for what would seem to be a simple thing!  I note that part of the complexity is due to the additional need to selectively apply the overlay depending upon the base map, something which GM still cannot do natively.  Thanks for the code - now proceeding to de-jquery it

Answer (score 2):

Your question had two parts:

1. To automatically show your custom overlay only when certain maptypes are active, you need to listen to the `maptypeid_changed` event on the `map` object. You will have to add/remove your overlay in that event listener.
2. There is not currently a way to add your own overlays/maptypes to the default maptype controls in a hierarchical fashion. See and star this issue for further details: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2490

Comment: 1. Thanks. Thats what I'm already doing right now. Google's documentations on th page I've link to in my question above sounded like there is a way to do this automatically by just linking the overlay to a base map type. I was hoping for an official statement from google employees to see, if doku is wrong or current API. I've asked this questions in google groups fisrt, but they've redirected me to here, since they've moved their support to here.

Comment: It's been a longstanding issue, but surprisingly one that doesn't get that much attention (as you can see by the number of stars on the issue I linked). If you want an official answer from Google, you should submit this to a Google Maps API Office Hours session. They announce the office hours on their Google+ page: https://plus.google.com/u/0/104063627743574070634/posts

Comment: 2. Yes, looks like there is no way BTW: The I think the doku on this point was changed some days ago. I was sure, they had mentioned a way to add a overlay layer to the mapTypeControl. The link to the corresponding example was broken on that time. The guy here ran into the same issue and found the same confusing docs.

And thanks for the link, but it doesn't contain any answers, just more questions. :-(

Comment: It is a feature that existed in the v2 maps that has never been implemented in v3. You can always develop your own custom control.

Comment: Yes, actually I've done that and imitated the exact style of the original google controls. But this is a feature which definitely should by supported natively so that look an feel of the control keeps up whenever google changes the interface (they've already done this several times in V3).

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1.)** I created example where selecting ROADMAP you can view specific overlayMapType (and hiding it with other modes), copy&paste to your test.html, view and enjoy! hopefully you can edit this to fit your needs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Overlay MapTypes</title>
    <link href="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>

      function CoordMapType(tileSize) {
        this.tileSize = tileSize;
      }

      CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
        var div = ownerDocument.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = coord;
        div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
        div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
        div.style.fontSize = '10';
        div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
        div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
        div.style.borderColor = '#AAAAAA';
        return div;
      };

      var map;
      var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033,-87.6500523);

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                                          mapOptions);

        // Insert this overlay map type as the first overlay map type at
        // position 0. Note that all overlay map types appear on top of
        // their parent base map.
        map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));

        // we check mapType when it is changing
        google.maps.event.addListener( map, "maptypeid_changed", function( evnt ) {
            if(map.mapTypeId === "roadmap") {
                // show my custom map layer - but only if its not already there
                // note: you could also check more specifily your map type here
                if(map.overlayMapTypes.getLength() == 0) {
                    map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));
                }
            } else {
                // if something else, remove it 
                // note: you could also check more specifily your map type here, but for now
                // we just check if something is already there
                if (map.overlayMapTypes.getLength() > 0){
                    map.overlayMapTypes.removeAt(0);
                }
            }
        });     

      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 640px; height: 480px;">map div</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Question 2.)** Tried but it was impossible (highly protected), use google custom map controls instead - that seems to be only option :(

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls

**Edit:**

Have you tried adding google road map type as own base layer so you could give it own name like in this example(view upper right corner selections): https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-base?hl=fi and then you would add overlay map (like in my example) over that google map where you display CoordMapType grid(or overlay map which you want). This way you would not yet get that checkbox but at least you could view it inside normal google map controllers with **own selection and name**? I dont have now time to test this theory cos im at work lol. :)

But basically you could accomplish then dropdown where is

1. Map (google road map)
2. My layer (google road map where is your overlay map above it, or several) ?

Alternatively you could try to use console.log(map); and try to find more ways than just:

```
CoordMapType.prototype.name = 'My base layer';
CoordMapType.prototype.alt = 'My base layer map type';
```

..maybe there is somewhere that checkbox option hidden if this already creates as a base layer selection. Those checkbox stuff must be always overlay map selection toggle.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but thats not what I was looking for. Please see my edits and comment on other answers. I'll wait some more day for an official answer form google to clear up the confusion on the docs. Otherwise i'll give the bounty to you for working out this helpful example code, if any other will run into the same problem.

Comment: ok @LeJared I updated my answer but that might be closest it can get